# SQL select 3 random rows non-recurring in the last query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Considering my first query is selecting 5 last rows from the table named `table1` like that:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5
```

How can I manage my second query to get any 3 random rows, excluding the last 5 (so there is no way that I'd get any of the 5 rows from the first query)?

I thought about limit, but I had no luck constructing the query.

Meanwhile, I insert the id's from the first query into an array, and checking them against the random ones. But I wonder if there is an easier way to accomplish that (maybe pure SQL)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT t.* FROM table1 t, (
    SELECT id FROM table1 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5,1
) as x
WHERE t.id <= x.id
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 3
```

Comment: @error_die it's far more efficient to just pass in the IDs you already have.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 
WHERE id NOT IN (?, ?, ?, ?, ?) 
ORDER BY RAND() 
LIMIT 3
```